# Units in Angular Material - why px not rem / em

Tags: css, angular-material

I have a question:

Recently I see a direction in CSS frameworks to switch to rems/ems (Bootstrap 4 went this way, Semantic UI has it as well). I really like this approach as it is really easy to scale "application/components size" with roots `font-size` or with browser default font size.

Do you know why Angular Material does not use it? I see, (almost) everything is in px. I guess approach with relative units is much better, more powerful, and does not create issues

Answer (score 6):

To quote *jelbourn* from the Angular team:

> We don't use em or rem because we have no control over the context
>   that influences the final size. However, with the typography extension
>   to theming, you should be able to customize the styles to use a custom
>   size.

Source: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5299#issuecomment-313743595

Not really detailed, but at least an answer ;)

Comment: There is now a pull request to fix this issue that is targeted for the next major release.
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15580